# Chrome Automation Extension has crashed when trying to run protractor test

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

I am gaining experience with Protractor and am using the example test to see how it works. The test is located in `xampp/htdocs/my-dev/test-automation-playground/poc-basic-integration-flow/node_modules/protractor/`

In there we have a `conf.js` and an `example_spec.js`. To run the test, we enter the protractor folder using git bash, and type `protractor conf.js`.

When I try to run the example test provided by Protractor, my browser opens and I get the following error: `Chrome Automation Extension has crashed...`. See below:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in the browser:

[image]

I've looking into Chrome extensions and there is no such extension there. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I simply start Git Bash without admin rights and I am not getting this error anymore. Also changing browser to Firefox in config resolves this issue most of the time.